# Why is $\int_0^x f(x) dx$ wrong?

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, notation

As soon as I entered higher education we stopped using functions of $x$ as the upper limit if we were integrating using a function application on $x$ like $f(x)$.

So we were told that an integral of the form:

$$\int_0^x f(x) dx$$

Was considered incorrect, why is this technically incorrect?

Is it due to the 'bound' occurrences of $x$? Or some other reason? Why do we tend to introduce a 'dummy' variable like the following:

$$\int_0^x f(s) ds$$

In this case, is the bound variable's 'scope' limited to the integral, can I take a function's value at a 'free' occurrence $x$ and also use it in the integral, and have it keep it as the same variable?

Comment: For not having very confusing things when writing $\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^x f(x) dx$ (which should give of course $f(x)$)

Comment: Notation is to be understood. If you define it, there is no problem. Writing $\int_{0}^{x}f(x)dx$ is not wrong, only can be confusing. Writing this forces the person reading to understand that the $x$ in $f(x)dx$ is not the same as that in $x$.

Comment: It's a bad habit to use the same notation for different objects in a single expression. Why force your reader to guess which "$x$" you mean at any given point?

Comment: @JeanMarie why is this confusing, is it because we will think that this is $f'(x)$?

Comment: It is technically wrong because limit of integration and variable of integration must be marked with different symbols, otherwise we don't know which $x$ is argument of $f(x)$. But this notation is often used as synonym of $\int_0^x f(s)\,ds$.

Comment: I will say it another way: if you write your integral $\int_{t=0}^{t=x} f(t) dt$, what would it mean to write $\int_{x=0}^{x=x} f(x) dx$ ?

Comment: Let consider discrete analog: $\sum_{i=0}^i f(i)$. Does it have sense at all?

Comment: @user37577 . You may also want to consider $\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^x f(y,x)dy$ which has a clear meaning. Now replace the $dy$ by $dx$ and the $y$ by $x$ which gives  a totally confusing expression: $\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^x f(x,x)dx$

Comment: @JeanMarie I would say they are the same, but the use of equals when $x$ is bound and then free is not great.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Purely technically speaking, it is *not* wrong. But it is very bad form, and can lead to a lot of confusion quickly. The confusion comes from two concepts clashing with each other. That is, in the expression

$$\int_0^x f(s)ds,$$ it is immediatelly clear that $x$ is a free variable, and $s$ is not a free variable. In other words, the question

> What is the value of the expression $\int_0^x f(s)ds$ when $x$ equals $3$?

is clearly a well defined question with a single correct answer. Even more importantly, *that answer can easily be obtained by just replacing all instances of $x$ with $3$*. On the other hand, the question

> What is the value of the expression $\int_0^x f(s)ds$ when $s$ equals $3$?

is clearly an ill posed question.

---

In your case, however, some of the instances of $x$ are *free* variable, while others are not. In particular, the $x$ in $f(x)$ and the $x$ in $dx$ is not a free variable. Therefore, the question

> What is the value of the expression $\int_0^x f(x)dx$ when $x$ equals $3$?

is still a well posed question, and the answer is $$\int_0^3 f(x)dx$$ which can be obtained by replacing all cases where $x$ is a **free** variable with $3$.

However, and this is the important part, this answer can now no longer be obtained by simply replacing all instances where $x$ appears with $3$. And this can become very painful very soon. For example, say we have another function, $g(x)$. Then, we want to multiply your expression with $g(x)$. Well, what we get is $$g(x)\int_0^x f(x)dx$$ but then what we **cannot** do is say that that is equal to $$\int_0^x f(x)g(x) dx,$$ but we **could** have said that $$g(x)\int_0^x f(s)ds= \int_0^x g(x) f(s)ds.$$ In other words, the notation is constraining our ability to manipulate the expression.

Comment: I'm actually a little bit confused by your last simplification, is it that $x$ is independent of $s$ and treated as a constant? Like as done in multiple integration?

Comment: @user37577 Exactly that. It is in fact true, for every collection of numbers $a,b,C$, that $$C\cdot \int_a^b f(s)ds = \int_a^b C\cdot f(s)ds$$ and so in particular, it is true for $a=0, b=x, C=g(x)$.

Comment: How do you know that $x$ in $f(x)$ is not free $x$?

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu Well, technically, I understand the $dx$ to mean "this bounds every instance of "$x$" between the symbol $\int$ and the symbol $d$". But again, people could argue against that, and invite even more confusion, which further strengthens my point.